# How to supply default values to mutable attributes using python attrs?

Tags: python, python-attrs

Just started using python attr, which looks great.  The package allows the easy creation of empty mutable parameters by using a factory to create new objects, but the intended method of populating these empty objects with default values isn't clear to me.  For example, this works to create a new list with a default value, but the default gets lost in the method call:

```
import attr; import typing

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class C:
    x: int=66
    # I want loi as a list with default value [1,2,3]
    loi: typing.List[int] = attr.Factory(list)

    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        self.loi.extend([1,2,3])

cx = C()
cx.loi = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: the factory you pass to it must return the default value you want, no? You passed `list` as a factory, and `list()` returns an empty list: `[]`, so pass a function that returns `[1,2,3]` instead

Comment: thanks -- wanted to avoid hiding defaults in another method, but just learned that lambda doesn't require a variable!  = attr.Factory(lambda: [1,2,3]) works, and is clear and simple enough for me.

Comment: @ricopan why don't you turn that comment into a proper answer?